# Vertical align listbox to bottom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, vertical-alignment, longlistselector

I need to layout my listbox like on this picture

[image]

I have tried everything to do that both for listbox and longlistselector..

```
 <ListBox WP7Panels:DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="MsgControlsList" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                              Height="600" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Bottom" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Bottom" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <WP7Panels:DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <HistoryClasses:HistoryElementTemplate WP7Panels:DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </WP7Panels:DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    </WP7Panels:DockPanel>
```

..but still I have top vertical alignment of the listbox.

[image]

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: What is the code around your listbox? Maybe a Grid or StackPanel?

Comment: Yeah. It is wrapped by <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"> ... </Grid>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set the height of your listbox the items are on the bottom of the screen.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="600"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <TextBlock Text="Test"/>

     <ListBox Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Item"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Test"/>

  </Grid>
```